# Netbeans Java Debugger claims that ((true && false) == true)

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I just encountered something that defies my understanding of logic. How can the situation below occur?

[image]

I've tried all the usual approaches to remedy this; clean/build, restart netbeans, etc. but the problem persists. Variable `complete` is always true, no matter what I do. I even replaced `left` and `right` with `true` and `false` boolean values respectively, but no change. What did work, was a refactor rename of the variable, but when I changed it back to the original, the problem resurfaced. There are no class members named the same way.

What's going on? Have I finally lost my mind, or should that variable have a value of `false`?

This is with Netbeans 7.3.1 on Windows.

**Edit01**

I'll try to prove it to the unbelievers that this is actually happening, when I get access to my work computer in a week or so. In the mean while, just take my word for it. THIS IS NOT A PRANK nor did it happen due to my lack of knowledge of debugging with Netbeans.

I do remember doing a bunch of svn switch-to-copy commands before this occurred, but not for the project where this code resides in (dependencies). A clean/build should have taken care of any inconsistencies anyways. I also did not remember to clear the Netbeans cache, which I now regret.

**Edit02**

Haters gonna hate, but as I feared, after returning to my workstation, I can no longer reproduce this issue. It pisses me off to admit this, but I have no proof whatsoever that this had ever happened. All I did was: woke up my pc from hibernation, undid a refactor rename of my variable, which was the last thing I had done before finishing my work, a clean/build and then another debug run. Everything just..works.

Comment: Beautiful, simply beautiful. java doesn't know how to do boolean operations...

Comment: No, HighCore is correct. The program misbehaves accordingly, @ikegami.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does the code enter the following `if` block? `complete` is `true` and `context.isEmpty()` is `false`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, no. That condition was not fulfilled, since `context` was not empty while debugging (that condition worked as expected).

Comment: Your code is evil and the source code of the program must be burned during a ceremony (after printing on perforated tractor feed paper) by priests and senior system architects.

Comment: It's either a poor Photoshop joke, or you modified the code while debugging...

Comment: You almost certainly did not recompile and so are debugging old byte code vs new source

Comment: Just because you modified left/right in the debugger when stopped at line 527 doesn't mean that line 525 is executed again.  Put the breakpoint on line 525 and let's see what the values say.

Comment: @Elist, I did not photoshop this. Like stated in my question, I clean/built and even restarted Netbeans and the issue did not go away. It would be impossible to keep a debugger session open during IDE restarts, to my knowledge.

Comment: @JasonNichols, originally, there were no left and right variables in my code. I split the expression in order to see what's going on. The debugger indicated a value of `true` with the following expression: `start <= offset && stop + 1 >= offset`, which seemed wrong to me, given that start and stop had a value of 14 and offset was 31.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about a freak glitch in NetBeans.

Comment: @Boann which proves my point... Thanks.

Comment: @HighCore You sure seem threatened by Java.

Comment: @Boann yes, I'm actually threatened by systemical inefficiency and backwardsness. You're 100% right. It is a threat to the entire human race, indeed.

Comment: @HighCore Inefficiency is only a threat if you're in a hurry. But happily, time is not finite. Closed platforms are the real threat.

Comment: @boann Well, I'm glad that everyone is happy in your hippie world full of butterflies and rainbows, but in the software development industry, EVERYTHING is a hurry. everything must be done yesterday. There is NO time to deal with crappy IDEs and platforms who think that `true == false`. That's what sent me to the hospital, shitty oracle / java platforms and bosses in a hurry. Thankfuly, I managed to get rid of the shitty java stuff by moving to .Net development. I still have bosses in a hurry, but at least I can trust my platform now.

Comment: @HighCore Join the hippies. It's nice here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of possibilities, but I don't believe it is internally wrong in the JVM. The debugger is probably simply tricked or bugged.

1. Some optimization is going on under the hood that causes `left` and `complete` be the same variable on the stack. So this would roughly means that your code got optimized to this:

   ```
   boolean left = (start <= offset);
   boolean right = (stop + 1 >= offset);
   left = left && right;   // reused "left" instead of new variable "complete"
   ```

   However, as far as I know, Java compilers don't do this sort of optimization. Can someone confirm or give details if this is not true? (Maybe javac or the JIT does this?)
2. NetBeans debugger is really bugging. From my C++ debugging experience, there actually existed a bug in a debugger (sounds funny, right) that causes the debugger to be unable to read integer values from memory correctly. Sometimes the results were off. This doesn't mean anything in this case, but it actually is possible that debuggers do have bugs.

   I remember I've been searching for hours to fix a bug in my code I discovered by debugging. But there was no bug. At least not in my code. The debugger reported me some values in memory, but were wrong.

If this weird behavior happens always, then try to put a debug statement behind it:

```
System.out.println(left + " && " +  right + " == " + complete);
```

I bet the output will be correct. Try to run the debugger also with this line added. If such an optimization happens as I described, it should be gone, because it can't reuse `left` anymore.

Comment: The original statement was `boolean complete = start <= offset && stop + 1 >= offset`, which was the one misbehaving. I split the expression, because I did not understand how it could be returning true. So I don't think the case in 1. applies to my issue. Note that it was still returning true even after I changed it to `boolean complete = true && false` and a clean/build.

Comment: The reason why I started debugging this code in the first place, was that my program was misbehaving in an unexpected way. I'm almost sure that your `System.out` would act the same way as the debugger, since the flow of the program (following what's in the screenshot) was altered accordingly. I can't say for sure though.

Comment: Can't you put that print statement in your code to see the results?

Comment: I will. Once my vacation is over.

Comment: Huh? :P You went on vacation between 19 hours ago and now? Enjoy it :)

Comment: Yep. Happened in my last hour of work... A pre-xmas miracle of sorts.

Comment: Since I have no way of reproducing my issue (see my last edit) I'll probably never get to the bottom of what was really going on. This was the most helpful answer, so I'm choosing it as the one that answers my question. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I replicated your code and here is what i found:

[image]

Comment: Is the "compelte" spelling mistake in the output intentional, or part of the conspiracy? ;-)