# Why is my Java "if" statement only being triggered if I have a watch on it in Netbeans?

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

I am doing some work that ties in to Apache Batik ( don't think this is relevant but you never know ) and I am running into some weird behaviour that I can't figure out the reason for.

The following bit of code is calculating the height of a line of text, so it can start the next line in the correct position:

```
protected double paintTextRun(TextRun textRun, double x, double y, int lineCount, EMFGraphics2D g2d) throws IOException 
{
     AttributedCharacterIterator runaci = textRun.getACI();
     char c = runaci.first();
     TextPaintInfo tpi = (TextPaintInfo) runaci.getAttribute(PAINT_INFO);
     if ( tpi == null || !tpi.visible )
     {
         return y;
     }
     setFont(runaci, g2d);
     g2d.setPaint(tpi.fillPaint);
     g2d.writeString(getTextFromACI(runaci, x, y);

     if (  runaci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE) != null )
     {
        y+= (float)runaci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE);
     }
     else if ( textRun.getLayout().getBounds2D() != null )
     {
         Double height = textRun.getLayout().getBounds2D().getHeight();
         if ( height != null )
         {
            y+=height/lineCount;
         }
    }
    return y;
    }
```

The thing that is confusing me is that when I place a breakpoint on the `y+= (float)runaci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE);` line, it is never triggered, the condition always falls through to the `else` side of that statement. And yet if I watch the value of `runaci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE)` in Netbeans it never appears to be null. In fact placing a watch on the exact statement from the `if` condition consistently evaluates to `true` even when the code is falling through to `else`. It's quirky.

However if I place a breakpoint on the `if (  runaci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE) != null )` line, it evaluates to `true` and so I go into the first half of the if...else block. Take out the breakpoint and it goes back to the `else` side.

Is this some kind of quirky bit of JVM optimisation or is there some kind of evaluation bypass bug that my limited recent Java experience has left me unprepared for?

Edit to add: Comments suggested a problem with the currently running IDE/debugger, but on a new day after restarting the computer and cleaning/rebuilding everything, the same problem manifests.

Comment: I had a similar issue, usually retyping the code, and restarting the IDE/computer solves the issue.

Comment: Luis has a point.  I'd do a clean and build, see if the behavior goes away.  If it doesn't, try logging instead of a debugger.  Sometimes there can be timing issues or other problems caused just by attaching the debugger itself.

Comment: It happened to me sometimes with the (buggy?) debugger. Then I fall back to do some logging to know what happens at runtime. I guess it is something with Swing/AWT thread vs. debugger interception.

Comment: Maybe check your toString() methods for side effects

Comment: What is returned from getAttribute?  It seems odd to me that you test it for null, but cast it to float.  If it returns a primitive, you should not test against null; if it returns an object, you should not cast it to float.

Comment: @arcy pretty sure that GetAttribute is pulling an object, which in this case is a `Float` - because if any attribute is unset it needs to return null, but as I'm just dabbling my toes into Java after years of other languages there are unquestionably going to be things that I miss and I'll double check it.

Comment: Why are you including `y+=` in the watch? Wouldn't it be safer to watch this: `(float)runaci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE);` and thereby avoid side effects when debugging

Comment: @vikingsteve - good point, bad typing on my part, I meant I place a _breakpoint_ on that line and watch the value of the attribute. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I feel better now. Watch expressions with side effects can cause all sorts of weird problems..... I would go thru and clear out all your other watches, just in cases there is something there interfering with the state... :)

Comment: You say that you watch `runaci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.Size)` but your condition is for `runaci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE)`. Is this a typo or do you actually have two fields in TextAttribute named `Size` and `SIZE`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am the king of typos apparently!

Comment: Had something similar happen to me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745964/netbeans-java-debugger-claims-that-true-false-true). To this day I still have no idea what caused the problem and what made it go away. Give it a few more days? :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the *why* of it, but if I assign the result of the `runaci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE)` call as a variable, it behaves as one might expect.

```
  Object textSize = runaci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE);
  if (  textSize != null )
     {
        y+= (float)textSize;
     }
     else if ( textRun.getLayout().getBounds2D() != null )
     {
         Double height = textRun.getLayout().getBounds2D().getHeight();
         if ( height != null )
         {
            y+=height/lineCount;
         }
    }
```

Probably good policy to work that way in any case- possibly this is a side effect of some optimisation aimed at preventing repeat calls to the same method requiring repeat evaluation.